# speedtest-cli works in console, but not as script

Tags: python, python-3.x, speed-test

I am trying to use the speedtest-cli api. Copied part of the code from official wiki (and removed unused stuff):

```
import speedtest
s = speedtest.Speedtest()
s.get_best_server()
s.download()
```

In python console I get everything ok:

```
>>> import speedtest
>>> s = speedtest.Speedtest()
>>> s.get_best_server()
{HIDDEN}
>>> s.download()
37257579.09084724
```

But when I create .py file and run it I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'SpeedTest'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your script also named speedtest?

Comment: it is named st.py, but tried renaming to STT.py, still doesnt work

Comment: Do you have a file in the same directory as `st.py` called `speedtest.py` ? (or a speedtest.pyc) ?

Comment: I had, but removed them now. Still the same. E: Tried copying to new folder, still same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As mentioned in the comments, you have a file with the same name and it is conflicting with the import. Since you have moved the file, restarting the console should work.**

The code below will also extract the results into a dictionary and make it possible to access the results.

```
import speedtest
s = speedtest.Speedtest()
s.get_best_server()
s.download()
s.upload()
res = s.results.dict()
print(res["download"], res["upload"], res["ping"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue because I had installed both speedtest and speedtest-cli.
Using `pip uninstall speedtest` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue because the name of my file was speedtest. When I change the name to something new. It works fine for me.

```
import speedtest
wifi  = speedtest.Speedtest()
print("Wifi Download Speed is ", wifi.download())
print("Wifi Upload Speed is ", wifi.upload())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ok Here is the Solution to this Problem

1-uninstall `speedtest`  and `speedtest-cli`  if you have both  installed

2- install only  `speedtest-cli`  `pip install speedtest-cli` this will install the package in the main python environment

3-`CTRL+P` select  `interpreter` then  select your main python not any environment

4-it will work fine

**Reason for this error**

(you install the package in your main python environment and you usually open your IDE and run a virtual environment)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking speedtest is imported properly

```
import speedtest
print(dir(speedtest))
```

it should display properties of speedtest