# AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, speed-test

As the title says, I'm getting this error when trying to run this simple Python code:

```
import speedtest

r = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

Which results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/XXXX/YYYYYY/VSCode/Poli.py", line 3, in <module>
r = speedtest.Speedtest()
AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'
```

I've looked through all the posts I could find here in SE and on the web:
[getting an AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693550/getting-an-attributeerror-module-speedtest-has-no-attribute-speedtest)
[python 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249874/python-speedtest-has-no-attribute-speedtest)
[speedtest module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990177/speedtest-module-in-python)
[speedtest-cli works in console, but not as script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854444/speedtest-cli-works-in-console-but-not-as-script)
https://cloudstack.ninja/pratik-amonkar/how-can-i-fixed-error-of-speedtest-module/

All I could make out is that a speedtest.py exists somewhere in my project folder and it is messing things up, but I cannot find this particular file. I've reinstalled the package several times, changed my filename and tried other virtual environments as well. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: `import speedtest; print(speedtest.__file__)`

Comment: Right -- you need to look at what you *do* have as `speedtest`.  @user2357112supportsMonica gave you a "quick strike" to check.  If this interests you, look up the various package inspection methods available in Python.

Comment: Just a guess - is it maybe `speedtest.SpeedTest` instead of `speedtest.Speedtest` ?

Comment: As the first comment suggested, I ran that code and it gave me this:
C:\Users\XXXX\YYYY\VSCode\speed\lib\site-packages\speedtest\__init__.py.

Which is a file that only contains the following lines:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__version__ = "0.0.1"

I have no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used `pip install speedtest` probably thats whats causing the problem. Thats the wrong package installed.
You have to uninstall the package `speedtest` using `pip uninstall speedtest` and instead install `speedtest-cli` using `pip install speedtest-cli`. The first line `import speedtest` is actually importing speedtest-cli.

*Note that you cant have both installed because then your script is actually trying to modify the file `speedtest.py` which was created when you did `pip istall speedtest`

Answer (score 0):

check if you already installed the speedtest.
if its installed then uninstall it `pip uninstall speedtest`
and just install `pip install speedtest-cli`
then try to run your script it will work.